# How to concatenate the index passed as a parameter in a function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

An input field is iterated in an array of items:

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) of items" :key="i">
    <td><input type="text" name="hour[]" id="hour[]"></td>
    <td><input type= "checkbox" name="disable" v-on:click="disabled(i)"></td>
</tr>
```

Is this how to write the function of `disabled(i)` ?

```
disabled(index){    
    $('#hour['+index+']').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try next code example:

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) of items" :key="i">
   <td><input type="text" name="hour[]" :id="'hour-' + i"></td>
   <td><input type= "checkbox" name="disable" v-on:click="disabled(i)"></td>
</tr>
```

function:

```
disabled(index){    
   $('#hour-' + index).attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: You can see a example in this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-rd9tdk?file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an element with `#hour[i]`

So you can change input element id

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) of items" :key="i">
    <td><input type="text" name="hour[]" :id=`hour[${i} ]`></td>
    <td><input type= "checkbox" name="disable" v-on:click="disabled(i)"></td>
</tr>
```